# First file that prestashop calls?

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I am using prestashop and I would like to know what file does Prestashop calls first?

I would then set a cookie in that file that can be accessed globally.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the really first one but it calls index.php, init.php, config.inc.php and the class Dispatcher at first, have a look to this file and set your cookie in the one you prefer. However why would you need that ? Isn'it "cleaner" to create a module or sth to do so ?